# alternative way of providing index to querySelectorAll by :even and :odd

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get even **(div)elements** and give them **different class Names** compared to **odd (div) elements** in which they will have **different class names** also, I want to write inside **querySelectorAll()** function to get even (.project) class and to get odd (.project) class without providing index like [0], [1],...etc. is there a way to do something like that?
here is there code for explanation.

here is the original code:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.project')[0].classList.add('EvenProject');
document.querySelectorAll('.project')[1].classList.add('OddProject');
document.querySelectorAll('.project')[2].classList.add('EvenProject');
```

here is what I want to implement:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.project:even').classList.add('EvenProject');
document.querySelectorAll('.project:odd').classList.add('OddProject');
```

I also tried this code, by querySelector(), but It doesn't work.

```
 document.querySelector('.project:even').classList.add('EvenProject');
```

thanks for you help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**NOTE:** *This answer assumes all `.project` elements are all children of the same parent.*

You can use `document.querySelectorAll('.project:nth-child(even)')`, check out [EVEN AND ODD RULES](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html) but, you can do the same thing purely in CSS:

```css
.project {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1em;
  background-color: black;
}

.project:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: blue;
}

.project:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="project"></div>
<div class="project"></div>
<div class="project"></div>
<div class="project"></div>
<div class="project"></div>
```

Comment: Yep, but I want to do this with js, because I'm using bootstrap classes ;)

Answer (score 2):

It'd only be possible if there's a parent component for all `.project`s whose children can be selected with `nth-child(even)` or `nth-child(odd)` - for example, with

```
<div>
  <div class="project"></div>
  <div class="project"></div>
  <div class="project"></div>
  <div class="project"></div>
</div>
```

you could then do

```
for (const project of document.querySelectorAll('.project:nth-child(even)')) {
  project.classList.add('EvenProject');
}
for (const project of document.querySelectorAll('.project:nth-child(odd)')) {
  project.classList.add('OddProject');
}
```

Or if the HTML is like

```
<div>
  <div>
    <div class="project"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="project"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="project"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="project"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

you could do the same sort of thing with the selector `:nth-child(even) > .project`. But not all possible layouts of the `.project`s could be selected with a single selector string like you want - you may have to iterate over the odd and even indicies of the collection manually and add the appropriate index to each.

Comment: Thank you my brother, your answer is totally correct

Comment: but can I ask a question, I don't under this part of code : for(const project of )?! why not just: var variable = document.getEle.....etc?

Comment: by the way you forget right parenthesis ) for both the for loops.

Comment: Because `var variable = document.getEle` will put the collection into a variable, but you still need to iterate over the collection. I like taking the more direct route and iterate over the collection directly instead of putting it into an intermediate variable (which takes more code and doesn't help anything, if this is all the collection is being used for in the script)

Answer (score 1):

```js
const projects = document.querySelectorAll('.project');

projects.forEach((el, i) => {
    if (i % 2 === 0) {
        el.classList.add('red')
    } else {
        el.classList.add('yellow')
    }
})
```

```css
.project {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: gray;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
}

.red {
    background: red;
}
.yellow {
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="project"></div>
<div class="project"></div>
<div class="project"></div>
<div class="project"></div>
<div class="project"></div>
<div class="project"></div>
<div class="project"></div>
<div class="project"></div>
<div class="project"></div>
<div class="project"></div>
<div class="project"></div>
<div class="project"></div>
<div class="project"></div>
<div class="project"></div>
<div class="project"></div>
<div class="project"></div>
<div class="project"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Details are commented in example**

```js
// .forEach() tag of NodeList... 
document.querySelectorAll('.project').forEach((tag, idx) =>
  // If the index is even...
  idx % 2 === 0 ?
  // ... add .black and .even+index classes...
  tag.classList.add('black', 'even' + idx) :
  // ... otherwise, add .white and .odd+index classes
  tag.classList.add('white', 'odd' + idx)
);
```

```css
html {
  font: 300 2ch/1 'Segoe UI'
}

body {
  background-color: grey;
}

.project {
  height: 1.2rem;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 7px;
  outline-width: 3px;
  outline-offset: -4px;
  outline-style: outset;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  text-align: center;
}

.black {
  outline-color: white;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.white {
  outline-color: black;
  background-color: white;
}

.black::before,
.white::before {
  content: attr(class);
}
```

```html
<section class='project'></section>
<section class='project'></section>
<section class='project'></section>
<section class='project'></section>
<section class='project'></section>
<section class='project'></section>
<section class='project'></section>
<section class='project'></section>
<section class='project'></section>
<section class='project'></section>
```

Comment: your answer is really amazing, than you brother.